# Sanitize complex objects using express validator

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

If I have a potentially deep, complex object (nested arrays, arrays of objects) that I want to sanitize using `sanitizeBody`, is there a way to globally sanitize every property/value in the object without resorting to looping through each item?

```
let obj = {
    name: 'Bob',
    age: 30,
    hobbies: [
      { 
        title: 'Soccer',
        skill: 'Terrible'  
      },
      { 
        title: 'Football',
        skill: 'Great'  
      }
    ],
    friends: {
      count: 30,
      happiness: 50
    }
  }
```

I could just as well flatten all the values into an array, and then  cycle through each and apply `sanitizeBody(obj).escape()` for example to each, but I'm wondering if I'm even approaching this correctly.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "sanitize"?

Comment: Sanitizing input values to prevent XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have.
Use below code snippet to sanitize globally.

```
sanitizeBody('*')
    .trim()
    .escape()
```

You can refer [this github repo](https://github.com/gurucharanmk/express-mongoose-jwt-restful/blob/master/src/app/api/todo/request.rules.js) for express-validator.(This repo isn't completed yet).

Comment: How does this actually work? Does express-validator have its own looping mechanism that hits every prop/value and sanitizes it?

Comment: I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'escape' of undefined` when I call `req.sanitizeBody`